# PowerShell Script - Is it possible to retrieve info on PowerApps included in a Azure Tenant?

Tags: azure, powershell, powerapps

I'm wondering it's possible to create some Powershell script in order to gather all possible information on all PowerApps included in Azure Tenant.
I need to collect the owner, connectors, usage stats and stuff like that.
I know there's this report:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/move-environment-tenant

But Power Apps analytics reports do not display model-driven apps data. Only canvas apps related data is displayed.

Any comments will be more than appreciated. Many Thanks!

Comment: SO, has rules we are to follow: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). That being said, if a service/solution/API (Azure, etc.), does not expose it, then you can't get it, as it's by design.

Comment: As per Microsoft: [Admin Analytics for Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/analytics-powerapps) As noted by you already. Yet, if you don't know, know that there are cmdlets for PowerApps [PowerShell support for Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

The PowerApps [PowerShell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-powershell) have modules that will display all PowerApps in your tenant. Specifically  the `Get-AdminPowerApp` cmdlet.

**This will get you some nice output:**

`Get-AdminPowerApp | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File ./test.txt`

Comment: How to get also model-driven apps, command: "Get-AdminPowerApp " seems that only returns Canvas apps.